# Unable to get returned data in redirected page from previously sent form

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, axios

I need some help understanding the concepts needed to get my application to work. I am running two instances of `localhost`, one on `5000:` and one on `8000:`. One is a Flask instance (backend) and the other is a VUE instance (frontend). On my frontend, I have an `onSubmit()` function that does two things:

1. Sends the form data to the `Flask` instance via `axios.post`
2. Redirects the frontend to a result webpage.

On my backend, my Flask instance is supposed to return the information I need.

```
    if request.method == "GET":
        #Accessing page for first time
        response_object['msg'] = "Waiting for user input"
    elif request.method == "POST":
        #Form has been submitted
        data = request.get_json()
        user = parseFormData(data)
        itinerary = getResults(user)
        return itinerary
```

I am unsure / unable how to check if this is working. On the redirected page, I have the following method that is called when the page is created.

```
        getResponse(){
            const path = "http://127.0.0.1:5000";
            axios.post(path)
            .then((res) => {
                this.tmp = res.data;
                console.log(this.tmp);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            });
        },
```

I am unable to get anything from this page actually. Any advice on where to go from here will be appreciated!

Edit:
The problem appears to lie in the sequence of events. On my `Frontend`, the form is submitted then the page is immediately redirected to a result page. While this is happening, my `Backend` receives the data, processes it and returns the information. That information appears to be lost. I believe this is sort of an example of async but I am unfamiliar with that concept as of now.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Too many mystery functions like `parseFormData`. Check the server logs--are there errors? Is the request arriving? If not, did you try adding print statements to see what's going on in the request? Check develoepr tools as well to make sure the request looks as you expect. Where's the payload on the post body sent by axios? Sorry for the bombardment of questions, but there are many things that look potentially wrong or unclear here.

Comment: I believe the error is not with the functions but rather the sequence of events that happen .I am quite new to async content. I will edit the question to give a bit more insight.